# Extracting assembly instructions from ELF ARM /bin binaries

Tags: assembly, arm, qemu

I'm running an ARM virtual machine using QEMU, and I wanted  to disassemble the bytecode from some standard `/bin` functions, such as `mount`, `mkdir` etc, to get the assembly instructions.

What I have done is first do an object copy:
`objcopy -O binary --only-section=.text mkdir mkdir.bin`
Then disassemble:
`objdump -m ARM -b binary -D mkdir.bin`

However, the assembly code I get is rubbish, with several undefined instructions errors. 
I've also tried disassembling forcing thumb-mode:
`arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -m ARM -b binary -D -Mforce-thumb mkdir.bin`
And here again, the instructions seem to be rubbish.

What I mean by rubbish is instructions which, although technically correct, make no sense.

I'm lost as to why this is happening, and I'm not sure where the problem comes from. Is it the commands which are wrong? Should I not expect to get ARM assembly instructions?

Note: This is the tutorial I've followed to install QEMU https://translatedcode.wordpress.com/2016/11/03/installing-debian-on-qemus-32-bit-arm-virt-board/

Comment: Try `objdump -d binary` where `binary` is the binary you have.  `objdump` understands ELF binaries.  There's no need to first convert them to a different format.

Comment: Note that ARM binaries often contain literal pool interspersed with code.  If the appropriate meta data is missing (e.g. if the binary is stripped), objdump has no way to tell them apart from instructions and will try to disassemble them, leading to nonsensical results.  You need to manually guess what is a literal pool and what not.

Comment: @old_timer are you sure? From my understanding of ELF, it follows a structure with sections. What the command is meant to do is extract the .text section which is supposed to be code (see for instance ELF wiki page: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#/media/File:ELF_Executable_and_Linkable_Format_diagram_by_Ange_Albertini.png ). Most of the files in /bin are not actually binary but ELF

Comment: @fuz I see, that would make sense. Is there anyway to guess that?

Comment: @Dominus It's usually fairly easy to see because the instructions that come out are generally fairly nonsensical.

Comment: @Dominus `objdump` understands ELF.  With option `-d` it disassembles only those sections that usually contain code.  No need to extract sections first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try it:

so.s

```
.globl _start
_start:
add r0,r1,r2
add r1,r2,r3
ldr r3,=skip
bx r3
.word 0x12345678
.hword 0xaaaa
.thumb
.thumb_func
skip:
add r0,r1,r2
add r1,r2,r3
```

and try it:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-as so.s -o so.o
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D so.o

so.o:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <_start>:
   0:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
   4:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
   8:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 1c <skip+0x6>
   c:   e12fff13    bx  r3
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  14:   1888aaaa    stmne   r8, {r1, r3, r5, r7, r9, fp, sp, pc}

00000016 <skip>:
  16:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
  18:   18d1        adds    r1, r2, r3
  1a:   00000000    andeq   r0, r0, r0
    ...

Disassembly of section .ARM.attributes:

00000000 <.ARM.attributes>:
   0:   00001541    andeq   r1, r0, r1, asr #10
   4:   61656100    cmnvs   r5, r0, lsl #2
   8:   01006962    tsteq   r0, r2, ror #18
   c:   0000000b    andeq   r0, r0, fp
  10:   01080206    tsteq   r8, r6, lsl #4
  14:   Address 0x0000000000000014 is out of bounds.
```

Yes, objdump disassembles everything, including data and other sections, but oh well. Notice how it got thumb vs arm...

Can be a linked binary as well.

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-ld -Ttext=0x8000 so.o -o so.elf
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -D so.elf

so.elf:     file format elf32-littlearm


Disassembly of section .text:

00008000 <_start>:
    8000:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
    8004:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
    8008:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 801c <skip+0x6>
    800c:   e12fff13    bx  r3
    8010:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
    8014:   1888aaaa    stmne   r8, {r1, r3, r5, r7, r9, fp, sp, pc}

00008016 <skip>:
    8016:   1888        adds    r0, r1, r2
    8018:   18d1        adds    r1, r2, r3
    801a:   80170000    andshi  r0, r7, r0
    ...
```

Yes, this is going to be a mess in general:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-objcopy -O binary so.elf so.bin
arm-linux-gnueabi-objdump -m ARM -b binary -D so.bin

so.bin:     file format binary


Disassembly of section .data:

00000000 <.data>:
   0:   e0810002    add r0, r1, r2
   4:   e0821003    add r1, r2, r3
   8:   e59f300c    ldr r3, [pc, #12]   ; 0x1c
   c:   e12fff13    bx  r3
  10:   12345678    eorsne  r5, r4, #120, 12    ; 0x7800000
  14:   1888aaaa    stmne   r8, {r1, r3, r5, r7, r9, fp, sp, pc}
  18:   000018d1    ldrdeq  r1, [r0], -r1   ; <UNPREDICTABLE>
  1c:   00008017    andeq   r8, r0, r7, lsl r0
```

It got the arm ones right but not the thumb ones, and won't.  Make it thumb only, it will get the thumb ones but not the arm and never will.

Comment: Try `-d` instead of `-D`.

Comment: If you want to see the other sections, why not `-sd`.  Disassembling them doesn't make too much sense anyway.

Comment: fine fuz I will try that been quite happy with -D for 15-20 years only x86 is where I have issues with -D so will try that there.

Comment: You could have gotten your answer in with -d before the OP selected this one, you can still put yours in and the OP can change their selection.

Comment: Your answer is already very good.  There's nothing of value I could add beyond what I commented.